# How to index the Values property of C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Using the  Values property of C# Dictionary,

```
var  myDict =  Dictionary < string, object> ;
```

How would I get the values in

```
  myDict.Values
```

I tried

```
var theVales = myDict.Values ; 
object obj = theValues[0] ;
```

But that is a syntax error.

Added:
I am trying to compare the values in two dictionaries that have
 the same keys

Comment: The attached link might also be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  The values do not have a fixed order.  You could write the values into a new `List<object>` and index them there, but obviously that's not terribly helpful if the dictionary's contents change frequently.

You can also use linq: `myDict.Values.ElementAt(0)` but:

- The elements will change position as the dictionary grows
- It's really inefficient, since it's just calling `foreach` on the Values collection for the given number of iterations.

You could also use `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.  That maintains the values in order according to the key, which may or may not be what you want, and it allows you to access the values by key or by index.  It has very unfortunate performance characteristics in certain scenarios, however, so be careful about that!

Here's a linq solution to determine if the values for matching keys also match.  This only works if you're using the default equality comparer for the key type.  If you're using a custom equality comparer, you can do this with method call syntax.

```
IEnumerable<bool> matches = 
    from pair1 in dict1
    join pair2 in dict2
        on pair1.Key equals pair2.Key
    select pair1.Value.Equals(pair2.Value)

bool allValuesMatch = matches.All();
```

If you require that all items in one dictionary have a matching item in the other, you could do this:

```
bool allKeysMatch = new HashSet(dict1.Values).SetEquals(dict2.ValueS);
bool dictionariesMatch = allKeysMatch && allValuesMatch;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use [`Enumerable.ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) if you *really* had to, but you shouldn't expect the order to be stable or meaningful. Alternatively, call `ToArray` or `ToList` to take a copy.

Usually you only use `Values` if you're going to iterate over them. What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you understand that the order of entries in a `Dictionary<,>` is undefined?

EDIT: It sounds like you want something like:

```
var equal = dict1.Count == dict2.Count &&
            dict1.Keys.All(key => ValuesEqual(key, dict1, dict2));

...
private static bool ValuesEqual<TKey, TValue>(TKey key,
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict1,
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2)
{
    TValue value1, value2;
    return dict1.TryGetValue(out value1) && dict2.TryGetValue(out value2) &&
           EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(value1, value2);
}
```

EDIT: Note that this isn't as fast as it could be, because it performs lookups on *both* dictionaries. This would be more efficient, but less elegant IMO:

```
var equal = dict1.Count == dict2.Count &&
            dict1.All(pair  => ValuesEqual(pair.Key, pair.Value, dict2));

...
private static bool ValuesEqual<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value1,
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2)
{
    TValue value2;
    return dict2.TryGetValue(out value2) &&
           EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(value1, value2);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to compare the values in two dictionaries with the same keys but it sounds like I should iterate through the dictionaries?

Comment: @TheMoot: You *certainly* shouldn't rely on the ordering, no. Will edit.

Comment: You could improve the performance by calling `dict1.All(pair => ValuesEqual(pair, dict2))` and modifying `ValuesEqual` accordingly.

Comment: @phoog: yes, I wondered about that. I preferred the appearance if this one, but I agree it's more expensive. Will add a note when I get time.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @JonSkeet's answer, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is backed by a HashTable, which is an un-ordered data structure.  The index of the values is therefore meaningless- it is perfectly valid to get, say, `A,B,C` with one call and `C,B,A` with the next.

EDIT:

Based on the comment you made on JS's answer ("I am trying to compare the values in two dictionaries with the same keys"), you want something like this:

```
public boolean DictionariesContainSameKeysAndValues<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict1, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2) {
    if (dict1.Count != dict2.Count) return false;
    for (var key1 in dict1.Keys)
        if (!dict2.ContainsKey(key1) || !dict2[key1].Equals(dict1[key1]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Indexer propertie to lookup the string Key.
It is still not an Index but one more way:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
class Client
{
   private Dictionary<string, yourObject> yourDict 
      = new Dictionary<string, yourObject>();

   public void Add (string id, yourObject value)
      { yourDict.Add (id, value); }

   public string this [string id]      // indexer
   {
   get { return yourDict[id]; }
   set { yourDict[id] = value; }
   }
}

public class Test
{
   public static void Main( )
   {
      Client client = new Client();
      client.Add("A1",new yourObject() { Name = "Bla",...);
      Console.WriteLine ("Your result: " + client["A1"]); // indexer access
    }   
}
```